# ffmpeg unable to save a frame at specific time

Tags: ffmpeg

I followed [Im getting error "deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly using ffmpeg".. can someone check my code below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038294/im-getting-error-deprecated-pixel-format-used-make-sure-you-did-set-range-corr) to save a frame from a video but the saved frame is of timestamp 00:00:00 instead of the given timestamp

```
$ ffmpeg -i 001\ Introduction.mp4 -ss 00:03:12.00 -vframes 1 side_view.jpg
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.0 (Gentoo 9.3.0 p2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg-4.2.2/html --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --cc=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc --cxx=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ --ar=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar --optflags='-march=native -O2 -pipe' --disable-static --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --disable-stripping --disable-optimizations --disable-libcelt --disable-indev=oss --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=oss --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-bzlib --disable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-debug --disable-gcrypt --disable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gpl --disable-hardcoded-tables --enable-iconv --disable-libtls --enable-libxml2 --disable-lzma --enable-network --enable-opencl --disable-openssl --enable-postproc --disable-libsmbclient --enable-ffplay --enable-sdl2 --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-xlib --enable-libxcb --enable-libxcb-shm --enable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-zlib --disable-libcdio --disable-libiec61883 --disable-libdc1394 --disable-libcaca --disable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libpulse --enable-libdrm --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libcodec2 --disable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libbluray --disable-libgme --disable-libgsm --disable-libaribb24 --disable-mmal --disable-libmodplug --enable-libopus --disable-libilbc --disable-librtmp --disable-libssh --disable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-librsvg --disable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --disable-libzvbi --disable-appkit --disable-libbs2b --disable-chromaprint --disable-cuda-llvm --disable-libflite --disable-frei0r --disable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --disable-ladspa --enable-libass --disable-libtesseract --enable-lv2 --enable-libfreetype --disable-libvidstab --disable-librubberband --disable-libzmq --disable-libzimg --disable-libsoxr --enable-pthreads --disable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmp3lame --disable-libkvazaar --disable-libaom --disable-libopenh264 --disable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --disable-libtwolame --disable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 --disable-neon --disable-vfp --disable-vfpv3 --disable-armv8 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-mipsfpu --disable-altivec --disable-amd3dnow --disable-amd3dnowext --disable-aesni --disable-avx --disable-avx2 --disable-fma3 --disable-fma4 --disable-sse3 --disable-ssse3 --disable-sse4 --disable-sse42 --disable-xop --enable-pic --cpu=host --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --enable-manpages
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '001 Introduction.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:09:40.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1981 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1835 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 1280x108, 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2020-05-20T08:15:54.000000Z
File 'side_view.jpg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55e27e819520] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'side_view.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=5.2 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=0.00313x    
video:44kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

In the above output, notice `time=00:00:00.03` despite the given `-ss 00:03:12.00`.

**Update**

`ffmpeg -i "001 Introduction.mp4" -ss 00:03:12.00 -vframes 1 -report -copyts side_view.jpg`

https://gist.github.com/GowthamKudupudi/d3703f990548819a5bcd5e72bd5c0449

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg resets output timestamps to start from zero, unless the user expressly adds flags to override it. So, nothing wrong or unexpected here.

Comment: the image being saved is not the one I want.

Comment: As per the log, the 5762nd frame is being saved. For a constant 30 fps stream, that's timestamp of around 3m12s.

Comment: but that's not the frame being saved!